# Borrowing punctuation from another typeface

Tags: typography, typefaces, best-practice

I am designing a piece of editorial and using Univers throughout, except for the pull quotes where I have used the quotation marks from Gotham instead as I feel they are more distinctive and appealing. This also means I have to change any other punctuation marks in the pull quote to those from Gotham for the sake of consistency.

Would this be considered bad design? Will I be confusing the reader? Should I revert back to using just Univers?

[image]

Comment: Why do you feel all other punctuation should follow? If Gotham's quotes are distinctive enough from the other font, they will stand on their own.

Comment: Only because I have used the Gotham quotes at the same size as the rest of the pull quote text, so in comparison to apostrophes and commas, for example, I feel you can notice this mismatch of punctuation

Comment: That's without changing the rest of the punctuation - I feel the apostrophe clashes the most

Comment: As I said in my answer, change the quotation marks—not the rest of the punctuation.

Comment: I agree it clashes but that is because the quotation marks are perceptively smaller than the body, you need to increase their size. Different fonts will have different perceived sizes at the same point size. Or just use Univers for the quotes. Or leave it as is. Most people won't notice. But don't change the punctuation in the body of the quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, do whatever looks best—that being said, you should use the normal punctuation in the body of the quote.

Using different quotation marks isn't unheard of, they are usually styled differently to the body of the quote anyway. Just search for 'Pull quote design' in your favourite search engine:

[image: pull quote design example]

[image: pull quote design example]

Using punctuation from a different typeface in the body of a text isn't needed. Punctuation is designed as a part of the typeface and using the punctuation from a separate typeface is going to look out of place.

If the problem is that the quotation marks look too similar to the body of the quote—change them. Even if that is only making them slightly bigger or changing the color. Changing the body of the quote shouldn't be your only solution.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think its that big of a deal, I'm sure it will go unnoticed. Once you know the rules, break em :p

Comment: Could you add some more explanation to what you mean? Here on StackExchange we prefer more full answers. As is, this fits better as a comment

Comment: Alright much appreciated, I'm pretty new to this website so I wasn't sure of any expectations. Will keep this in mind moving forward!